# Draw pixel trace by moving an object

Tags: python, animation, pygame, pixel

I'm working in Python using Pygame and I'm wondering how to draw pixels depending on moving some object with cursor keys.

So, what I want to do is to draw a "trace of movement", for example when the player is moving his object rightward, the program must draw pixels behind this object from the start of movement to the end of movement.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: not exactly... object is moving with cursor keys. typical movement with event keys (event.key).

i just need some example to draw pixels behind that moving object.

Comment: if the object is moving by cursor key input surely you have *some* code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with [`surface.set_at()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_at):

```
surface.set_at((x, y), color)
```

The x and y is the position of your moving object. Color is a RGB three element tuple like `(100,0,200)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a track of the past positions of the object..
In the code below, a pygame.Rect is being moved around with arrow keys.

The parts you'll be interested in are in the `Player` class, namely

1. `lasts` (list)

   - This list keeps a record of the previous positions of the player.
2. `update_list()` (function)

   - This function manages the list,

     - Adding the current position into the list.
     - Removing the first element, once the list is as long as `fade`.
3. `draw()`(function)

   - Actually only the for loop here, it uses indexes and draws the fading Rects.

> **Note**: This is not the most efficient code.

**The Code**

```
import pygame

bg = (255, 255, 255)

def add_colors(color1, color2):
    retval = []
    for i in range(3):
        c1 = color1[i]
        c2 = color2[i]
        c = c1+c2
        if c > 255: # just basic handling
            c -= 255
        retval.append(round(int(c)))
    return tuple(retval)

def calc_colors(color, fade):
    retval = []

    # calculating the color change rate
    diff_color = []
    for i in range(3):
        diff = bg[i] - color[i]
        c_diff = diff/float(fade)
        diff_color.append(c_diff)
    diff_color = tuple(diff_color)

    # get the fading colors
    lastcolor = bg
    for i in range(fade):
        new_color = add_colors(lastcolor, diff_color)
        retval.append(new_color)
        lastcolor = new_color

    return retval[::-1]

class Player:
    def __init__(self, color, fade, pygame_Rect_args):
        """Give arguments as given to pygame.Rect"""
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(*pygame_Rect_args)
        self.size = self.rect.size
        self.vx = 0.0
        self.vy = 0.0
        self.lasts = []

        self.maincolor = color
        self.colors = calc_colors(color,fade)
        self.fade = fade


    def draw(self):
        for i in range(len(self.lasts)):
            pos = self.lasts[i]
            c_color = self.colors[i]
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, c_color, pygame.Rect(pos, self.size))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.maincolor, self.rect)

    def update_list(self):
        self.lasts.append(self.rect.topleft)
        if len(self.lasts) > self.fade:
            self.lasts.remove(self.lasts[0])

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += int(round(self.vx))
        self.rect.y += int(round(self.vy))

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:    self.vy -= 0.1
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:  self.vy += 0.1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:  self.vx -= 0.1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: self.vx += 0.1


player = Player((255,255,0), 10, (10,10,10,10))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            break

    if not running:
        break

    player.handle_keys()
    player.update_list()
    player.update()

    screen.fill(bg)
    player.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(40)
```

You may also want to do [this tutorial](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/category/pygame-tutorial/) (not the entire thing, but just the last part (#9))